# Domain Mapping On Wordpress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, dns, mapping, multisite

I'm trying to setup a bunch of websites on a Wordpress multisite installation with domain names from 1&1. So far, none of them are working. Anyone got a step-by-step walkthrough for getting the domain names to work?

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start is http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network which covers domain mapping, etc. Your 1&1 hosting account may not allow sufficient DNS options to allow domain mapping; see the linked docs at the Codex link above.